# update input value when state is updated reactjs

Tags: reactjs, fullcalendar

I'm using fullCalendar library, and I want to show a modal to add an event when some date is clicked in the calendar.

```
<FullCalendar defaultView="dayGridMonth" 
   plugins={[ dayGridPlugin, interactionPlugin]} 
   events={this.events}
   dateClick={(info) =>{
      this.setState({modal: true, addClass: {start: info.date}})
   }}
   editable='true'
/>
```

`this.state.modal` is the boolean that decides whether the modal should be shown or not.

In the modal, I have this input:

```
<Input type="datetime-local" name="course" 
       value={this.state.addClass.start} 
       onChange={this.handleForm} required
>
```

When the modal appears, I want it to show the date clicked as value of my input. `dateClick` successfuly changes the state, and store the date clicked, but when the modal appears, the input doesn't have any value.

When I searched for my problem, I didn't find any solution on how to change the input value when the state is changed. Doesn't any one know how to do it?

Comment: You might need to post a little more code. Where is `state` being set when you use it in `Input`? It should be set on the parent of `FullCalendar` and `Modal`. My guess is that you might be setting state in the modal and it's getting stale, but it's hard to tell without seeing the Modal code, or the parent where `state` lives. Could you update your question with that code as well?

Comment: Is `Input` a component?